# Sending alerts based on changes in lookup columns

Tags: 2013, 2010, alert

Scenario:

List A, called `Regulations`, stores info about some documents - like law regulations that are important to our business. It has several columns like `last update`, `document status` etc

List B, called `Responsible departments`, stores info about our company divisions and department's that are responsible for tracking any changes in documents from list A. So we have "many to one" relation between B and A.

List A

```
 - ID 1, Document 1, properties... 
 - ID 2, Document 2, properties... 
 - ID 3, Document 3, properties... 

 [...]
```

List B

```
 - ID 1, Division A, Department X, {Lookup:List A:ID 1 Properties} 
 - ID 2, Division A, Department X, {Lookup:List A:ID 2 Properties} 
 - ID 3, Division A, Department Y, {Lookup:List A:ID 1 Properties} 
 - ID 4, Division A, Department Y, {Lookup:List A:ID 2 Properties} 
 - ID 5, Division B, Department Z, {Lookup:List A:ID 3 Properties}
```

Now, users from any Division/Dept should be able to "subscribe" so they can get alert when any document, that is in their scope of interest, gets updated.

So when document (from List A) with ID 2 is changed alert goes to 3 groups:

```
 - Division A, Department X users, 
 - Division A, Department Y users, 
 - Division B, Department Z users,
```

And when ID 3 is changed there is only 1 alert for Division B, Department Z users

We planned to use native Sharepoint alerts (users would have to create personal views with filters like "Documents from division A and Dept X" and then create alert for that view) but

> main problem is that using native Sharepoint alerts there is no change
>   to List B elements when List A elements gets modified.

So no alert is created for this...

Our second try was to create workflow that updates List B entries when there are any List A changes - but it would update only 1st element on List B (workflow lookup for an element cannot return more than 1 value)

Any idea if we can use native sharepoint feature to do this or maybe there is any commercial plugin that will do this? We can use Sharepoint Foundation 2010 or 2013,

best! :)