# How to update multiple elements using workflow

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow

Can i use Sharepoint 2010 (or 2013) Foundation workflow to

1. start automatically when element on `List A` is changed (that's easy)
2. find and update (set one field) elements from `List B` that have lookup field value set to `Current element` (from List A)

e.g. I have `Books` and `Chapters` 1-to-many relationship and want to create a workflow that will start when I change anything in "Bible" and find and update all elements from `Chapters` list that have lookup field set to "Bible".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending alerts based on changes in lookup columns](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157283/sending-alerts-based-on-changes-in-lookup-columns)

Comment: The two questions are related but not the same, and how would anyone find information about updating related elements via workflow if they needed to search for `sending alerts` in the other question?

Answer (score 0):

In SP2013 workflows you can use "Update list item" activity.

1. Save NewData in a variable "SomeVar"
2. ADd "Update list item" activity.
3. Set "list=chapters"
4. Add "FieldName" field to be updated with value "SomeVar".
5. Change "Serch item" in the bottom of dialog form so that look through "ParentField" with value get from lookup value "CurrentItem:Id"

Comment: thanks, I will test this on SP2013, i assume that in 2013 they added a support for updating mulitiple rows?